# Discord radio bot randomly disconnecting

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Djs (**v12**)

Maybe someone is already familiar with this problem in their code and knows the solution.
After a few hours of listening, the bot just randomly stops playing music from the web by URL and leaves the voice channel.

Here's a bit of my code where the problem is hiding, thanks for any answers or solutions :-)

```js
const commands = {
    "play-join": {
        process: function(message) {
            
            if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "?play-join") {
        if (message.channel.type == "dm") return;

        const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === 'DJ')

        if (!role) return message.reply(`**DJ** role is not created`)
        if (!message.member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) return message.reply(`You need to have ${role} role.`);

        var shuffle1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * connect_log.length);

        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel
        if (voiceChannel) {

            if (!client.voice.connections.some(conn => conn.channel.id == voiceChannel.id)) {
                
            var EventEmitter = require('events');
            const emitter = new EventEmitter()
            emitter.setMaxListeners(0)

                message.member.voice.channel.join().then(connection => {
                        require('http').get("http://STREM_URL", (res) => {
                            connection.play(res);
                            message.channel.send(connect_log[shuffle1]);
                            connection.voice.setSelfDeaf(true);

                        });
                    });
                }
            } else {
                message.reply("Be in a Voice Channel!");
            }}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the node process falls asleep (???)

Comment: Hmm, in one way yes...
But in another way, it shouldn't do that.
If I would add reload command after time it would ruin the user experience, because there is few second refresh/connecting delay

Comment: Where are you hosting your bot?

Comment: currently on Heroku, one client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, I had figured it out.
If someone is having problems as I did, use **stateChange** and Idle event, then reconnect if the state changes from playing to Idle.
Thanks for your answers guys it really helped!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting your bot on **Heroku** you can try this:

- Add a new **file** named `Procfile` to your **root directory**
- Open the file and paste in this line: `worker: node index.js` and save it
- Push it to your **git repo**
- Open up your **Heroku project**
- Navigate to the **Resources** tab
- Now there should be a new option called `worker: node index.js`, edit it so you can activate it

Before hosting my bot on a **VPS** I hosted it on **Heroku** too and following this steps made my bot never fall asleep. Hope it helps for you too :)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem. I'm already running it the same way as you suggest

Comment: Are you running a **free dyno** on heroku?

Comment: Yeah, it's free. I have two accounts one with a credit card linked and another without, where I'm currently hosting it